# returning rows from one table based on a searching from a column or another table and writing the rows to a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```html
SELECT
    PartList.cprj,
    PartList.PartNumber,
    PartList.SWITEM,
    PartList.QTY,
    ItemMaster.dsca,
    ItemMaster.item

    FROM 
    SSIS.dbo.SWBOM as PartList
INNER JOIN
    ItemMasterRoutingPOC.dbo.[Item Master Data] AS ItemMaster ON ItemMaster.item = PartList.PartNumber 

UNION ALL

SELECT
    PartList.cprj,
    PartList.PartNumber,
    PartList.SWITEM,
    PartList.QTY,
    ItemMaster.dsca,
    ItemMaster.item

FROM 
    SWBOM PartList
 THIS SHOULD CHANGE BASED ON YOUR PART NUMBER SEQUENCE

INNER JOIN
ItemMasterRoutingPOC.dbo.[Item Master Data] AS ItemMaster ON ItemMaster.item = 

(CASE WHEN (ItemMaster.item=LEFT(ItemMaster.item,8) + '-XX') AND (ItemMaster.item=LEFT(ItemMaster.item,8) + '-X')


THEN (LEFT(PartList.PartNumber,8) + '-XX')
ELSE
(LEFT(PartList.PartNumber,8) + '-X')


END)
LEFT JOIN

(    SELECT
        PartList.PartNumber as FoundPartNumber
    FROM 
       SWBOM PartList
    INNER JOIN
        ItemMasterRoutingPOC.dbo.[Item Master Data] AS ItemMaster ON ItemMaster.item = PartList.PartNumber 


) IT ON IT.FoundPartNumber = PartList.PartNumber
WHERE
  IT.FoundPartNumber IS NULL
```

I'm new to this programming. I have 2 tables in two different databases. In the one table I have a PartNumber column, which contains many numbers that I want to cross reference in another table in a different database. So for every entry in the PartNumber column (cycling thru them) I want to match to the PartNumber column on the 2nd database. They may not have to be exact matches or I could search for the first 8 characters. So for every PartNumber search I would like ALL the rows from the second table to be inserted into a third table that would be in the same database as the first table.

I have tried to write some code but with my limited knowledge now very successful. The code is as such:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('FFGD.dbo.BAANExport') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE FFGD.dbo.BAANExport
GO

CREATE TABLE FFGD.dbo.BAANExport
(
    ITEM VARCHAR(512),
    PartNumber VARCHAR(512),
    QTY VARCHAR(512),
    dsca VARCHAR(512),
    Level VARCHAR(512),
    trid VARCHAR(512),
    cprj VARCHAR(512),
    mitm VARCHAR(512),
    pono VARCHAR(512),
    sitm VARCHAR(512),
    opol VARCHAR(512),
    qana VARCHAR(512),
    scpf VARCHAR(512),
    cwar VARCHAR(512),
    opno VARCHAR(512),
    cpha VARCHAR(512),
    exin VARCHAR(512),
    itlu VARCHAR(512),
    ssta VARCHAR(512),
)
GO


DECLARE PartNumber_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT PartNumber
FROM FFGD.dbo.ImportCSV;

OPEN PartNumber_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM PartNumber_cursor;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM PartNumber_cursor;
      Insert into FFGD.dbo.BAANExport
      Select * from BAANItems.dbo.ItemMaster, FFGD.dbo.ImportCSV
      where BAANItems.dbo.ItemMaster.PartNumber = BAANItems.dbo.ItemMaster.PartNumber

   END;


CLOSE PartNumber_cursor;
DEALLOCATE PartNumber_cursor;
GO
```

BAANEXport is the third table to be written to.
ImportCSV is the first table containing the part numbers I want to find in the second table.
ItemMaster is the second table containing the rows I want to extract.

I have not attempted to do try and search with not an exact match. I was trying to get some kind of output with exact at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to do a UNION to first pull the exact matches, and then pull in the non matches that follow the pattern you need. Here is the basic idea. You will need to change the JOIN I have highlighted a remark on here. Is the 'NO2-XXXX' portion fixed, and then you have variations thereafter?

I would need to understand more about the exact sequence on part numbers to give you the exact SQL, but this should get you close.

```
SELECT
    PartList.PartNumber
FROM 
    ImportCSV PartList
INNER JOIN
    ItemMaster ON ItemMaster.PartNumber = PartList.PartNumber  

UNION ALL

SELECT
    ItemMaster.PartNumber
FROM 
    ImportCSV PartList
-- THIS SHOULD CHANGE BASED ON YOUR PART NUMBER SEQUENCE
INNER JOIN
    ItemMaster ON LEFT(ItemMaster.PartNumber,8) = LEFT(PartList.PartNumber,8) 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        PartList.PartNumber as FoundPartNumber
    FROM 
        ImportCSV PartList
    INNER JOIN
        ItemMaster ON ItemMaster.PartNumber = PartList.PartNumber  

) IT ON IT.FoundPartNumber = PartList.PartNumber
WHERE
    IT.FoundPartNumber IS NULL
```

Comment: This is kinda the behaviour of the stored numbers in the ItemMaster: H01-0430-X
H01-0430X-X
H01-0430L-X
H01-0430R-X


H01-0430-XX
H01-0430X-XX
H01-0430R-XX
H01-0430L-XX

H01-0430\08\10
H01-0430\13\12

A23-1356-X
A23-1356-XX
A23-1356\10AC

Comment: Now I have to get the code to choose that if the exact match does NOT exist, it will choose to use a non exact match say with the -x. But if it does exist to use the exact match. I also found a part number that was preceeded by the letter C in many of the entires ie. CH01-0430\15\83.

Comment: After, this code has been properly developed and the table exists with the proper results, How would I go about sending this table using a http send in sql. Would the table have to be converted to any other format i.e json or comma delimited in order to be sent or can we send the table as is. I have no idea of how to code something as such. Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Still trying to figure this part out:  to choose that if the exact match does NOT exist, it will choose to use a non exact match say with a '-x'. But if it does exist to use the exact match. My understanding, is the above results table gives a cumulative result for all exact and non-exact matches based on part number with all the corresponding rows. How do I filter this now to the condition mentioned.

Comment: Was able to get everything working thru the conditions statement. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Awesome, Ben. Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you need a cursor. You can join both tables in a single SELECT by using the full 3-part path, and then go directly into your table. To do a match where the Part Number begins with the same part number in the parent table, use a like with a wildcard.

Something along these lines:

```
Insert into FFGD.dbo.BAANExport
    (PartNumber)
SELECT
    PartList.PartNumber
FROM 
    FFGD.dbo.ImportCSV PartList
INNER JOIN
    BAANItems.dbo.ItemMaster ItemMaster ON PartList.PartNumber LIKE  BAANItems.dbo.ItemMaster.PartNumber + '%'
```

Comment: I have implemented the code you shared and it works BUT only seem to grab 4 entries from the BAANItems.dbo.ItemMaster. I know there are many many more entries. Is there a more generic LIKE condition that I am missing. In the ItemMaster table, there could be entries as such, N02-1771-X, N02-1771-X-X, N02-1771-96\84\AC\83. Now the search PartNumber from table ImportCSV could be N02-1771\75\84\AC\72. I would like the search to be exact and if not grab the N02-1771-X or N02-1771-X-X.

Comment: I have edited the above code, to include a CASE statement, such that if a part number in the item master contains both -x and -xx to only return the -xx if the exact part number did not exist. Apparently the output for this yields only the -x when using the AND, and if using an OR gives -xx. I am not sure what is wrong with the conditioning. An example of data that I have is: N02-1771\75\84\AC\72, N02-1771-X, n02,1771-XX; A21-1098-X, A21-1098-XX; A56-8768-X. Some sets of data may contain all 3 but may not be an exact match so have to use a -X OR -XX. Some data may only contain a -X.

Comment: Also, I have a primary key in each of the tables which is a column named ID. The ID would have to coincide on another column in each of the table which is cprj which is the project number. Based on these factors as well with the case statement mentioned above I would like the query to return the part numbers that are a match or similar as was done in the query above. The only concern I have is that the IMPORTCSV table is a cumulative table that is always having a csv file appended to it.

Comment: Continued from last comment. I would like to have the query written above, only process the next csv that was appended not the entire table again. I only need the subset or recent cproj project number to be completed. But there is no way to exactly know the project number coming in. Is it possible? I have no idea how to tackle this?

Comment: The IMPORTCSV table was changed to SWBOM table in the above code.